# How can i change `keyword` color on runtime in `textarea` or `textbox`? Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a `textarea` i want that when i type keyword like `var` and press `SPACE`button then it's color will be `blue` on runtime.I defind many keyword my self.Not on button click its will be on runtime.How can i do this?Thanks.And i also want this `textarea` text in `codebehind`.I'm working in ASP.NET C# environment.Same like `SQL-QUERY-EDITOR`.
Here is my code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
var codeInput = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
var keywords = new Array("var", "if");
function checkHighlight(){
var codeInput1 = codeInput[0].value;
if(codeInput1 === keywords[0]){
 keywords[0].indexOf(codeInput1).className = "JSfunctions";
}
}
</script>
<style type="text/css" runat="server">
    #JScodeinputbox{font-family:Arial;}
  #JScodeoutputbox{}
    .JSfunctions{color:blue;}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
 <textarea id="JScodeinputbox" wrap="logical" rows="30" cols="70" onkeyup="checkHighlight();"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not possible in `textarea`. "The HTML `<textarea>` element represents a multi-line plain-text editing control." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: so how can i do this?I want this in `textarea` or `textbox` because i want to reterive this value in `codebehind` and pass to `sql-command` and execute the `sql-query` how can i do this?I think this is easy way

Comment: Use some RichText editors like TinyMCE, CKeditor, to list few. They take data (html) from textarea and show / edit it in WYSIWYG style.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev can you help me pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee sir Pleaseee..Here is my email `hameed7475@gmail.com`

Comment: If you a kind of DIY then you can read about `contenteditable` attribute. Else google for "javascript html editor". it will take minutes.

Comment: then after it can i get these values in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery:

```js
$("html").append("  <textarea id='text' type='text'> </textarea> "); //create an input box
$("html").append("  <input id='submit' type='submit'>  "); //create a submit button

$("input").css("border", "1px solid black");

$("#submit").click(function() {
  var unit = $("#text").val();
  if (unit == "var") {
    $("#text").css("border", "2px solid blue");
    $("#text").css("background", "blue");
  } else {
    $("#text").css("border", "1px solid black");
    $("#text").css("background", "white");
  }
});

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32) {

    var unit = $("#text").val();
    if (unit == "var") {
      $("#text").css("border", "2px solid blue");
      $("#text").css("background", "blue");
    } else {
      $("#text").css("border", "1px solid black");
      $("#text").css("background", "white");
    }

  }
});

$("html").append("(You can also press enter or space)");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Hameed did you include jQuery?

Comment: make sure you put inside of`<script type='text/javascript'> </script> `.